# Convert a Object [,] array into a dataset / datatable in C#

Tags: c#, arrays, multidimensional-array, datatable, dataset

C# Convert a Multi dimensional Object[,]array into a dataset / datatable

I have Object[,] and I am  passing that to function and I need to build Datatable

Here is my code I am trying this way

```
 public static DataTable ArraytoDatatable(Object[,] numbers)
{                 
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();

Console.WriteLine(numbers.Rank);
Console.WriteLine(numbers.Length);

for (int dimension = 0; dimension < numbers.Rank; dimension++)
{
    dt.Columns.Add("Column"+(dimension+1));
}

Console.WriteLine("Array");
for (int element = 0; element < (numbers.Length / numbers.Rank); element++)
{
    DataRow row = dt.NewRow();
    for (int dimension = 0; dimension < numbers.Rank; dimension++)
    {
        Console.Write("{0} ", numbers[element,dimension]);                    
        row["Column" + (dimension + 1)] = numbers[element, dimension];
    }
    dt.Rows.Add(row);
    Console.WriteLine();
}

Console.WriteLine("DataTable");
foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
{
    foreach (DataColumn column in dt.Columns)
    {
        Console.Write("{0} ", row[column]);
    }
    Console.WriteLine();
}

return dt;

}
```

Please help me if there is any other kind of approach

Error is here please take a look 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pzqui.jpg)

---

Another approach I  tried is

-`

```
public DataSet ToDataSet(Object[,] myData)
     {
     DataSet ds = new DataSet();

     // Test 2D array of Objects so that different data types 
     // can be in each element


     // Create a DataTable object. Each row in the table is one
     // row in the array
     DataTable dt = new DataTable();
     // Create DataColumns for each column in the row
     // each column is a element in the array param 1 is the name
     // of the column and param 2 is its data type
     DataColumn dc = new DataColumn("block", typeof(System.String));
     // Add this column to the columns collection of the data table
     dt.Columns.Add(dc);
     dc = new DataColumn("mode", typeof(System.String));
     dt.Columns.Add(dc);


     dt.Columns.Add(dc);










     for (var i = 0; i < myData.GetLength(0); i++)
         for (var j = 0; j < myData.GetLength(1); j++)
             dt.Rows[i][j] = myData[i, j];


     // Add the row to the DataTable
     // dt.Rows.Add(data);


     // If you need to add the DataTable to a DataSet
     // then execute the next two lines
     DataSet ds1 = new DataSet();
     ds.Tables.Add(dt);



     return ds1;
 }
```

`

Comment: You have shown what you have tried, does it work? What is wrong with it?

Comment: @tim Please see the image attached

Comment: Can you have the numbers in XML, or do you have to have them in an array? If you can have them in XML, it is as easy as calling the `DataTable.ReadXml()` function.

Comment: @RacilHilan .... Sorry i have tried that But its suitable for  single dimensional not for muti dimensional object [,] array

Comment: Why? XML is suitable to almost any kind of data including multi-dimensional which is very easy. Try something like `<col1>value1</col1><col2>value2</col2>`. I can post it as an answer if you like

Comment: By the way, I've tested your code and it worked. Here is a [fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/OBHUfg). Is your array huge? If so, you should use `numbers.LongLength` instead of `numbers.Length`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

How about this:

```
public static DataTable ArraytoDatatable(Object[,] numbers)
{                 
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    for (int i = 0; i < numbers.GetLength(1); i++)
    {
        dt.Columns.Add("Column" + (i + 1));
    }

    for (var i = 0; i < numbers.GetLength(0); ++i)
    {
        DataRow row = dt.NewRow();
        for (var j = 0; j < numbers.GetLength(1); ++j)
        {
            row[j] = numbers[i, j];
        }
        dt.Rows.Add(row);
    }
    return dt;
}
```

Usage:

```
var table = ArraytoDatatable(new object[2, 3] {
    { 1, 2, 3 },
    { 4, 5, 6 },
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Array.GetLength` to get the length of the dimensions of a multi dimensional array:

```
int width = numbers.GetLength(0);
int height = numbers.GetLength(1);

for (int w = 0; w < width; w++)
{
    dt.Columns.Add("Column" + (w + 1));
}

for (int h = 0; h < height; h++)
{
    DataRow row = dt.NewRow();
    for (int w = 0; w < width; w++)
    {
        Console.Write("{0} ", numbers[w, h]);
        row["Column" + (w + 1)] = numbers[w, h];
    }
    dt.Rows.Add(row);
    Console.WriteLine();
}
```

Output:

```
Cell 0|0 Cell 1|0 
Cell 0|1 Cell 1|1 
Cell 0|2 Cell 1|2
```

With this sample data:

```
object[,] objects = new object[2, 3];
int width = objects.GetLength(0);
int height = objects.GetLength(1);
for (int w = 0; w < width; w++)
    for (int h = 0; h < height; h++)
        objects[w, h] = string.Format("Cell {0}|{1}", w, h);
```

Comment: with this sample data its working fine but if  I pass my Object[,] unfortunately  its not display on grid view or Datatable which we created is not able to view it , but as you showed for small data yes! not for big data

Comment: @Ranju: how large is your array? Are you sure that it's not simply to large? Is the `DataTable` created successfully? Then it might be a different question since this task is solved.

Answer (score 1):

In case you want to know how to do it in XML, your function will be very simple:

```
public static DataTable ArraytoDatatable(string numbers)
{
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    ds.ReadXml(new StringReader(numbers));
    return ds.Tables[0];
}
```

And here is how you can write your xml and test it:

```
string xml = "<?xml version=\"1.0\"?><numbers>"
    + "<row><col1>1</col1><col2>2</col2></row>"
    + "<row><col1>3</col1><col2>4</col2></row>"
    + "<row><col1>5</col1><col2>6</col2></row>"
    + "<row><col1>7</col1><col2>8</col2></row>"
    + "</numbers>";

DataTable dt = ArraytoDatatable(xml);
Console.WriteLine("DataTable (" + dt.Rows.Count + " rows in " + dt.Columns.Count + " Columns)");
foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
{
    foreach (DataColumn column in dt.Columns)
    {
        Console.Write("{0} ", row[column]);
    }

    Console.WriteLine();
}
```

Here is a [fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/yBPNaq).